# Upload file using PHP from Compute Engine to Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

There seems to be no example application or demonstration of uploading files using PHP to google cloud storage from a PHP application hosted for example on Compute Engine.

I'm struggling to reverse engineer the google-api-php-client library to figure out how it's supposed to work.

I have looked at storage-getting-started-php on github but there doesn't seem to be anywhere in the script where there is an upload.

I could use the JSON library and write my own php file handling library but this seems unnecessary if the code has already been written in the php client library.

Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated.  I'm migrating a really high traffic site to compute engine.

Comment: I have contacted Google Support but apparently they also don't have any information on this.  They are asking developers.  I will post the answer here if they can provide me with one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been in contact with google support.  They've given me this code.  I haven't had the chance to test it yet though.

```
<?php
include 'lib/cms.php';
require_once('config.php');
require_once(MVC_ROOT . 'models/App.php');

ini_set("memory_limit", "-1M");
ini_set("max_input_time", "-1");
ini_set("max_execution_time", "-1");
set_time_limit(0);
ignore_user_abort();

$copyOrMove =  (SYSTEM_PLATFORM == 'gogrid') ? 'cp' : 'mv';

$cms = new CMS();
$dbh = $cms->dbh;

$data = $_POST['data'];
//$appcode = $cms->safeInput($_REQUEST['app']);
$appcode = $cms->getAppcode();
$type = $_REQUEST['type'];

$appdir = '../apps/' . $appcode;
if (!file_exists($appdir)) mkdir($appdir);
if (!file_exists($appdir . '/images')) mkdir($appdir . '/images');
if (!file_exists($appdir . '/images/org')) mkdir($appdir . '/images/org');
if (!file_exists($appdir . '/images/gallery')) mkdir($appdir . '/images/gallery');
if (!file_exists($appdir . '/images/30')) mkdir($appdir . '/images/30');
if (!file_exists($appdir . '/images/75')) mkdir($appdir . '/images/75');
if (!file_exists($appdir . '/images/200')) mkdir($appdir . '/images/200');
if (!file_exists($appdir . '/images/resources')) mkdir($appdir . '/images/resources');
if (!file_exists($appdir . '/attachments')) mkdir($appdir . '/attachments');


if ($type == "image") {

    $filename = 'homepage-' . date("Ymd-His") . '.png';
    $dir = "../apps/" . $appCode . "/images";
    if (!is_dir($dir)) {
        mkdir($dir, 0755, true);
    }
    //first lets delete the old ones...
    foreach (glob("../apps/" . $appcode . "/images/homepage*.png") as $killfilename) {
        echo "$killfilename size " . filesize($killfilename) . "\n";
        unlink($killfilename);
        exec("gsutil -m rm gs://gs.appbuild.io/apps/$appcode/images/homepage*.png");
    }

    //$filename='homepage.png';
    $file = "../apps/$appcode/images/" . $filename;

    $uri = substr($data, strpos($data, ",") + 1);
    file_put_contents($file, base64_decode($uri));

    $dir = "../apps/" . $appcode . "/images/resources";
    resizeImage($file, 640, 960, $dir . "/Default@2x.png");
    resizeImage($file, 640, 1136, $dir . "/Default-568h@2x.png");
    resizeImage($file, 320, 480, $dir . "/Default.png");

    $pathArray = array("../apps/$appcode/images/resources/Default@2x.png","../apps/$appcode/images/resources/Default-568h@2x.png","../apps/$appcode/images/resources/Default.png");

    exec("gsutil $copyOrMove ../apps/$appcode/images/$filename gs://gs.appbuild.io/apps/$appcode/images/");

    exec("gsutil -m $copyOrMove ". implode(' ',$pathArray) ." gs://gs.appbuild.io/apps/$appcode/images/resources/");

    $sql = "INSERT INTO appearance SET appearance_background_image='$filename', app_code='$appcode' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE appearance_background_image='$filename'";
    $stmt = $dbh->query($sql);
    $dbh = null;

    // return the filename
    echo URL_CDN_ROOT . "apps/$appcode/images/" . $filename;
} else if ($type == "icon") {
    $size = $_REQUEST['size'];
    $filename = 'icon_' . $size . '.png';

    $dir = "../apps/" . $appcode . "/images/resources";

    if (!is_dir($dir)) {
        mkdir($dir, 0755, true);
    }

    $file = $dir . "/$filename";
    $uri = substr($data, strpos($data, ",") + 1);
    file_put_contents($file, base64_decode($uri));

    resizeImage($file, 57, 57, $dir . "/icon_57.png");
    resizeImage($file, 57, 57, $dir . "/icon.png");
    resizeImage($file, 72, 72, $dir . "/icon_72.png");
    resizeImage($file, 114, 114, $dir . "/icon_114.png");
    resizeImage($file, 114, 114, $dir . "/icon@2x.png");
    resizeImage($file, 120, 120, $dir . "/icon_120.png");
    resizeImage($file, 175, 175, $dir . "/icon_175.png");
    resizeImage($file, 1024, 1024, $dir . "/icon_1024.png");

    $filepaths = array($filename, "icon_57.png", "icon.png", "icon_72.png", "icon_114.png", "icon@2x.png", "icon_120.png", "icon_175.png", "icon_1024.png");

    $fromArray = array();
    foreach ($filepaths as $filenm){
        $fromArray[] = "../apps/$appcode/images/resources/$filenm";
    }

    exec("gsutil -m $copyOrMove ". implode(' ', $fromArray) ." gs://gs.appbuild.io/apps/$appcode/images/resources/");   

    $app = new App($appcode);
    $app->setAppIcon(implode(',', $filepaths));

    echo URL_CDN_ROOT . "apps/$appcode/images/resources/$filename";
}

if (SYSTEM_PLATFORM == 'computeengine' && $appcode != '') delTree("../apps/$appcode"); 

function resizeImage($filename, $new_width, $new_height, $dirname)
{
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);
    $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
    $image = imagecreatefrompng($filename);
    imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);
    //$newfilename = $dir . "/icon_" . $new_width . ".png";
    imagepng($image_p, $dirname);
}

function delTree($dir) { 
    $files = array_diff(scandir($dir), array('.','..')); 
    foreach ($files as $file) { 
        (is_dir("$dir/$file")) ? delTree("$dir/$file") : unlink("$dir/$file"); 
    } 
    return rmdir($dir); 
} 

?>
```

Comment: Note this is loading the entire file into memory.  This probably needs breaking up into sections and each part uploading.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link from github. https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/tree/master/examples. My understanding also is that you need get an authorization token  in order to upload files using PHP.

Comment: I may be wrong but I looked at these examples at great length and couldn't find one for google cloud storage.  They were all for google drive when files were being handled.